# Batch command to remove a string pattern from input file

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to scripting.

I have a couple of files `File1.txt` and `File2.txt`. "RemPattern" is the pattern which I'm expecting to find and remove recursively from the above files.

Is it possible to remove them with the help of any windows or powershell batch command?

I have seen Get-Content can be used to remove an entire line of the matched pattern, but it doesn't fit for my case.

```bsh
(Get-Content 'File1.txt') -notmatch 'RemPattern' | Set-Content 'File1.txt'
```

Is it required to write a batch file to achieve this or is it possible to do it by batch commands?

Comment: Change `-notmatch` with `-replace` and you should be good to go

Comment: the rationale here is that `-notmatch` will skip the entire line where a match is found. Note that adding `-raw` was a good suggestion but that comment has been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out the `-replace` instead of `-nomatch`.

```
(Get-Content 'D:\File.txt') -replace 'RemPattern' | Set-Content 'D:\File.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming that you wanted to recurse through a set of files and not do them by manually typing the filenames. So you can:

```
Get-ChildItem F:\ -Filter File*.txt | Foreach-Object{
   (Get-Content $_.FullName) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'RemPattern'} | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

The filter here simply checks `File*.txt` which in your example will do the replacement for both `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` without havign to type out each file manually per line. You can change the filter as you please.